# How do I prevent the proprietary Linux ATI driver from detecting my screen's dpi?

Tags: linux, graphics-card, amd-catalyst

The proprietary ATI driver for Linux tends to misdetect dpi when I plug in different monitors (plugging into a TV over HDMI after using with a normal DVI monitor). Either it correctly detects it has a low dpi (and fonts are unreadably small) or it thinks it has a very high dpi (and fonts are absurdly large). How do I tell it to always use a specific dpi?

I have already set a DisplaySize in mm for "Configured Monitor" in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. It seems to lose track of this after a few mode changes with the `amdcccle` control panel.

Answer (score 1):

Use the MergedDPI option in your xorg.conf file.

Taken from the [radeon(4) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/4/radeon)

> Option "MergedDPI" "string"
>
> The driver will attempt to figure out an appropriate DPI based on the
> DDC information and the orientation of
> the heads when in merged framebuffer
> mode. If this value does not suit you,
> you can manually set the DPI using
> this option.
>
> For example, Option "MergedDPI" "100 100"
>
> The default value is undefined.

Comment: That's for the radeon driver. I am using fglrx.

Comment: ah sorry, try # man fglrx | grep dpi; I can't find it online.